# Regarding Timer - Developed a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework v4

Tags: timer, frameworks, bots

If the user is not responding back to the bot for a time interval of 2mins,Bot has to throw a default message like "Hey Are you there"..How can it be done .Tried with the all possible approaches,nothing worked.

Bot developed using Microsoft Bot Framework v4 - Coding done using node js. Tried with Setinterval,setTimer,node-cron,smart-timeout and other packages available.

```cs
var cron = require('node-cron');
async function getTimers(context) {
 cron.schedule('*/2 * * * *', () => {
  console.log('running a task every two minutes', context);
  return await context.sendActivity("Hey are you there");
 });
}
```

Comment: Please show the work that you have done so far.

Comment: var cron = require('node-cron');
                    async function getTimers(context){
                    cron.schedule('*/2 * * * *', () => {
                      console.log('running a task every two minutes',context);
                      return await context.sendActivity("Hey are you there");
                    });
                    
                    }

Comment: You can edit your own posts BTW.

Comment: Ya can edit ,,,added the code done so far

Comment: found any solution @VanthanaShree please post .. I am in a similar situation context is getting undefined / can not get proxy